# Cannot modify data on SD card

Tags: linux, sd-card

I have a strange SD-card. If I try to delete data or format card - after re-inserting card it turns back to initial state.

dmesg shows

```
[ 7207.910291] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
```

fsck says that

`0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.`

and any actions with fsck doesn't helps.

```
[14170.994718] mmc0: card 59b4 removed
[14174.915337] mmc0: new SDHC card at address 59b4
[14174.919760] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 USD00 7.36 GiB 
[14174.921347]  mmcblk0: p1
```

After deleting anything:

```
[14202.765458] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some   data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.

# fsck /dev/mmcblk0p1
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
Perform changes ? (y/n) y
/dev/mmcblk0p1: 1523 files, 115510/241028 clusters
```

After unmounting and mounting again all repeats.

Comment: Please post complete `dmesg` output concerning the card, especially if it's mounted read-only (which is an indication it's at the end of its life), what exactly you did with `fsck`, and any possible error messages during this. `fsck` *should* clear the dirty bit and repair the FS.

Comment: Maybe it's just a faulty SD card.